# PHP Insert/Update $_SESSION Variable into User Session from server

Tags: php, session, session-variables

So here's the scenario:
I have user SIDs stored in database while active and I want to change/set a $_SESSION variable in the user's session.  I do know there are other ways (Ajax, etc) to accomplish the same thing, but now I am intensely curious to see if there is a way to make this work.

Here's what I'm trying, User SessionID=1234567890 code, refreshed every 15 seconds:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['Message'])) {
    $msg=$_SESSION['Message'];
    $alert= "<br><script type='text/javascript'>alert('$msg');</script><br>";
    unset($_SESSION['Message']);
} else {
    $alert="<br>'Message' is NOT set.<br>";
}
```

And I run this on the server:

```
<?php
session_id('1234567890');
session_start();
$_SESSION['Message']="Hello!";
?>
```

And the result is the user session hangs on refresh instead of popping up the alert.

From the docs I have read, it seems like this is not specifically excluded, but I can see where it may cause slight security concerns.  I have no security concerns in this case.

So, is there any way to make this work?

Comment: BTW: NOTHING happens in httpd/error_log

Comment: Please provide more information. Your code appears to be correctly, presuming you've started session before check if $_SESSION["Message"] exists.

Comment: @ErnaniAzevedo Yes, I am starting session.  Unless you have something specific in mind, only other useful information is default PHP5x session handler and server script run as root on server CLI. User script run as apache.

Comment: found your bug, posted as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are maybe running into an Issue called "Session blocking".

If a PHP-Script is running, it will lock it's current session-object on a file-system-level. Other PHP-Scripts calling `start_session` for the very same ID will be stuck, until the first script has released the lock.

To avoid this, you can try to add `session_write_close();` to your script(s), whenever you are sure, that the current script does not need to store any more data to the session-file.

Afterwards, you can still read the session during script execution but no longer write.

Answer (score 0):

When you run PHP in CLI, it doesn't have session_path set. You'll need to execute the [session_save_path()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php) method and inform where your session files should be located.

For example:

```
bash# ls -al /var/www/tmp/sess_julp8r943vmbv18lhi651beu03
-rw------- 1 apache apache 19 Jun 20 21:09 /var/www/tmp/sess_julp8r943vmbv18lhi651beu03
bash# php -q
<?php
session_id ( "julp8r943vmbv18lhi651beu03");
session_start ();
var_dump ( $_SESSION);
?>
array(0) {
}
bash# php -q
<?php
session_save_path ( "/var/www/tmp");
session_id ( "julp8r943vmbv18lhi651beu03");
session_start ();
var_dump ( $_SESSION);
?>
array(1) {
  ["message"]=>
  string(7) "Hello there!"
}
```